# if user liked my fan page, what extra information can I get about that user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I'm an admin of Fan page with "like" gate (i.e. user has to like the page before he is able to see the content) - what information can I potentially get about the users who liked my page? Can I see what other pages they liked, and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only extra information you get is indication whenever he liked the page, nothing more.

Liking page doesn't grant your application access to user's details, so to get any info except some generic data in `signed_request`(like age range and locale) you need to authorize user.

Comment: do you have by any chance a link to FB docs where this is explained? Thanks!

Comment: The docs don't document thing in the negative - if there was a way to access user information without their permission you would probably have read about it on CNN - there is no functionality to get information about page fans other than the aggregate information which is available via the Insights interface or API